# Empty import table when linking with /INCREMENTAL:NO to import libraries of some dlls

Tags: visual-c++, dll, mingw, import-libraries

`/INCREMENTAL:NO` is default for Release configuration in visual c.

I've downloaded `FFmpeg git-3efe5e3 32-bit Dev` from http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/ .
It contains `.dll.a` and `.lib` files. I chose `.lib`. After compile the import tables for ffmpeg dlls are empty and the program crashes. If I enable `/INCREMENTAL`, it compiles and runs fine.

`test.c`:

```
void av_register_all();

int main() {
    av_register_all();
    return 0;
}
```

_

```
lib>cl test.c /link /incremental:no avformat.lib ws2_32.lib
lib>dumpbin /IMPORTS test.exe
...
    avformat-55.dll
                4080F4 Import Address Table
                4095E4 Import Name Table
                     0 time date stamp
                     0 Index of first forwarder reference


    KERNEL32.dll
                408000 Import Address Table
                4094F0 Import Name Table
                     0 time date stamp
                     0 Index of first forwarder reference

                  143 GetCurrentProcessId
                  110 GetCommandLineA
                  216 HeapFree
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known bug in `binutils` which is being used in Zeranoe builds of FFmpeg.
In Release builds of Microsoft Visual Studio by default in Linker options > Optimization > References = `/OPT:REF` which strips all FFmpeg references so you don't see them in `dumpbin /IMPORTS`.

You need to follow instructions [4.2.1 Linking to FFmpeg with Microsoft Visual C++](http://ffmpeg.org/platform.html#Linking-to-FFmpeg-with-Microsoft-Visual-C_002b_002b). There are two options. Either specify `/OPT:NOREF` in linker options which is not recommended due to increase of the size of an executable and increase initial loading time of an executable. Or generate new `.lib` and `.exp` files from `.def`, for example, for x86_64:

```
lib /machine:x64 /def:avcodec-55.def /out:avcodec.lib
lib /machine:x64 /def:avdevice-55.def /out:avdevice.lib
lib /machine:x64 /def:avfilter-4.def /out:avfilter.lib
lib /machine:x64 /def:avformat-55.def /out:avformat.lib
lib /machine:x64 /def:avutil-52.def /out:avutil.lib
lib /machine:x64 /def:postproc-52.def /out:postproc.lib
lib /machine:x64 /def:swresample-0.def /out:swresample.lib
lib /machine:x64 /def:swscale-2.def /out:swscale.lib
```

Another option is to build FFmpeg by youself.

Another option is to join FFmpeg dev community and move build system from autotools/autoconf/automake to CMake.

Moderators, please fix my broken english.

Comment: wow, I'd never imagine that you can make import library without .c file